# Fedora 20 - how to install applications?

Tags: linux, user-interface, installation, gnome, fedora20

I just installed Fedora 20 on my laptop.

I've never been the Administrator of a Linux machine and so...I don't know how to install application on it! :D

Could you please help me ?

I tried using some command like :

```
sudo apt-get ....
```

But it fails because something is not installed, and I also tried to use the new software center, but there are no applications inside, I can only see some squares with 3 points inside them and that's all.

I just started using Linux, so I'm sorry in advance if I'll make stupid questions!

Thank'you all!

Comment: apt-get is only suitable for debian based distributions. RedHat is none of those, it is rpm based. Try `man yum` or just the RedHat user guide (documentation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to type: `sudo yum install "whatever without parenthesis"`.

Or, switch to the root account and you won't have to type `sudo` in front of everything.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **yum install application** to install softwares on Fedora also refer http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Software-in-Fedora for your reference

Answer (score 1):

On Fedora 22, it seems the app for managing software is no longer `yum`, but `dnf`. So, first update by running `dnf updateinfo` and then run `gnome-software` which is a GUI, or `dnf search <something>`.

```
dnf search java
dnf install java-1.8.0-openjdk
```